# Custom hook inside useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook for reusing UseEffect

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function useGetList(getListFunc) {

    const [currentList, setCurrentList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            setCurrentList(await getListFunc())
        }
        fetchData();    
    }, [getListFunc]);

    
    return currentList
}
```

I can use this custom hook in a component directly.

```
 const currentStaff1 = useGetList(getStaffListFunc)
 console.log(currentStaff1)
```

But using it to set the default value of a state variable is giving an empty array []

```
const [currentStaff, setCurrentStaff] = useState(useGetList(getStaffListFunc))
console.log(currentStaff)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Sorry if this is an obvious debug and you've already checked it, but have you tried testing where things are in the render loop by calling a useEffect like: `useEffect(() => console.log(currentStaff), [currentStaff])`, just in case that the `console.log(currentStaff)` you have now is getting called before currentStaff has been updated? I had a similar issue earlier today with a userLogin, so I'm asking because it's on the front of my brain.

Comment: useEffect is similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. It will run when the Component is being mounted/updated and you are doing an async call in your custom hook. it won't wait until the promise is resolved. Try to set state in usEeffect with custom hook dependency

Comment: You shouldn't be calling useState inside useState. That's crazy

Comment: @JMadelaine   . I see the craziness now.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
const [currentList, setCurrentList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        setCurrentList(await getListFunc())
    }
    fetchData();    
}, [getListFunc]);


return [currentList] // return as array
```

and then in your component

```
const [currentStaff] = useGetList(getStaffListFunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved useEffect directly into the component, rather than the reusable custom hook, after realizing a state hook was used inside another statehook.